# Splitting a list in n amount of sublists

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for a way to slice a list into `n` amount of sublists

So for example if

```
    A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

If `n = 4` I want 4 different sublists

```
    B = [0,1,2]
    C = [3,4,5]
    D = [6,7,8]
    E = [9]
```

but the last sublist must not be bigger than the previous so  this wouldn't do

```
    B = [0,1]
    C = [2,3]
    D = [4,5]
    E = [6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: `[A[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(A),n)]` with the length of the sub lists `n` being `math.ceil(len(A)/num_lists_wanted)`

Comment: @dawg yes but what this does with A only creates 3 sublists, `n` is the number of sublists and not the number of elements in each sublist. This only creates `B = [0,1,2,3] C = [4,5,6,7] D = [8,9]` theres no 4th sublist

Comment: If I do `n=3; [A[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(A),n)]` I get `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9]]`

Comment: @dawg thats not what i really wanted, that creates 4 sublists of 3 elements each. `n` doesnt represent the number of elements but the number of sublists so what i essencially needed is `n=3` and i get `[[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9]]` cause then i have 3 sublists

Comment: `len(A)/4` is 2.5; `math.ceil(2.5)` is 3 so if you want 4 sublists you would have `n=math.ceil(len(A)/4)` What am I missing?

Comment: @dawg got it alright thanks

Comment: [Here](http://wordaligned.org/articles/slicing-a-list-evenly-with-python) what I was searching and was not able to find it duplicated questions:


    `def chunk(xs, n):
        '''Split the list, xs, into n evenly sized chunks'''
        L = len(xs)
        assert 0 < n <= L
        s, r = divmod(L, n)
        t = s + 1
        return ([xs[p:p+t] for p in range(0, r*t, t)] + [xs[p:p+s] for p in range(r*t, L, s)])`


Hope it would help someone (or even future me).